# Scraping a website with data hidden under “Lihat Selengkapnya”

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape description of products from `https://www.tokopedia.com/ofan-store8/xiaomi-redmi-9-ram-4-64gb-garansi-resmi-tam-purple?src=topads` and I want to get the data under 'Lihat Selengkapnya' button of the site. Is there anyway to scrape this?

Here is the html:

```
<div role="tabpanel">
   <ul class="css-1ijyj3z e1iszlzh2" data-testid="lblPDPInfoProduk">
      <li class="css-354z6m">
         <span>
            Kondisi<!-- -->: 
         </span>
         <span class="main">Baru</span>
      </li>
      <li class="css-354z6m">
         <span>
            Berat<!-- -->: 
         </span>
         <span class="main">500 Gram</span>
      </li>
      <li class="css-354z6m">
         <span>
            Kategori<!-- -->: 
         </span>
         <a href="https://www.tokopedia.com/p/handphone-tablet/handphone/android-os" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><b>Android OS</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="css-354z6m">
         <span>
            Etalase<!-- -->: 
         </span>
         <a href="https://www.tokopedia.com/ofan-store8/etalase/xiaomi" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><b>Xiaomi</b></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="css-1dwge1q">
      <span class="css-11oczh8 e1iszlzh0">
         <span class="css-17zm3l e1iszlzh1">
            <div data-testid="lblPDPDescriptionProduk">Produk segel<br/>Kualitas terjamin keasliannya <br/>bergaransi TAM<br/>Produk kami kirim dlm keadaan ssgel...<br/><br/>Note : <br/>UNTUK PARA PEMBELI MOHON DI BACA SEBELUM MEMBELI..... <br/><br/>untuk garansi Kami akan aktivasi sesuai dengan invoice pembelian di  TOKOPEDIA oleh Promotor Xiaomi kami dengan cara sebagai berikut : <br/><br/>imei handphone di sold out menggunakan sistem aplikasi yg ada di setiap handphone para promotor xiaomi... dan kami pastikan produk tdk lah di unboxing tp msh tetap dlm keadaan segel. mohon maaf kami tdk akan melayani komplain apabila aktivasi garansi sudah sesuai dengan invoice pembelian di tokopedia.  untuk para pembeli dgn  melakukan pembelian maka kami anggap sudah setuju dgn peraturan toko <br/><br/>JADILAH PEMBELI YG BIJAKSANA<br/></div>
         </span>
      </span>
      <button class="css-5lrz2e" data-testid="btnPDPSeeMore" type="button">Lihat Selengkapnya</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Actually the  content has a "Lihat Selengkapnya" button `<button class="css-5lrz2e" data-testid="btnPDPSeeMore" type="button">Lihat Selengkapnya</button>`. How can I trigger that button to fetch the whole content to this code below?

```
desc = []
quotes = soup.find_all('div', {'role': 'tabpanel'})
for item in quotes:

    descs = item.find_all('div', {'class': 'css-1dwge1q'})
    for each in descs:
        desc.append(each.text)
```

But it can't scrape contents under the 'Lihat Selengkapnya'

Comment: Here do just want to scrape the content or trigger a click event after finding the content ?

Comment: scrape contents after click 'Lihat Selengkapnya' button @sushanth

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to click as it is already present under one of the elements

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/ofan-store8/xiaomi-redmi-9-ram-4-64gb-garansi-resmi-tam-purple?src=topads', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
pprint(soup.select_one('[data-testid="lblPDPDescriptionProduk"]').get_text('\n'))
```

Another way of looking at same text:

```
print([i.string.strip() for i in soup.select_one('[data-testid="lblPDPDescriptionProduk"]').children if i.string])
```

or

```
[i for i in soup.select_one('[data-testid="lblPDPDescriptionProduk"]').stripped_strings]
```